# Removing or adding the empty word from a DFA

Tags: finite-automata

[image]

The title is my interpretation of this question. Below is what I have attempted so far:

Case 1: Ɛ ∈ L(M)

L(M<sub>1</sub>) = L(M)

L(M<sub>2</sub>) = {Q<sup>2</sup>, Σ<sup>2</sup>, q<sup>2</sup><sub>0</sub>, F<sup>2</sup>, <sup>2</sup>}

Q={q<sub>0</sub>, ... , q<sub>i</sub>}

Q<sup>2</sup>={q<sup>2</sup><sub>0</sub>, ... , q<sup>2</sup><sub>i+1</sub>}

Σ<sup>2</sup> = Σ

q<sup>2</sup><sub>i+1</sub> ∈ F<sup>2</sup> iff q<sub>i</sub> ∈ F

<sup>2</sup>(q<sup>2</sup><sub>i+1</sub>, a) = (q<sub>i</sub>, a)

Case 2: Ɛ ∉ L(M)

L(M<sub>2</sub>) = L(M)

L(M<sub>1</sub>) = {Q<sup>1</sup>, Σ<sup>1</sup>, q<sup>1</sup><sub>0</sub>, F<sup>1</sup>, <sup>1</sup>}

...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have so far looks good but incomplete. Here's a description of what's left; writing it out in symbols is left as an exercise.

In the first case, if the language already contains the empty string, we're done and can use the automaton for the language directly with no modification. If it does not contain the empty string already, we can add a new initial state and have it transition like the original initial state. If we leave all other transitions alone and make this new initial state accepting, we will accept the empty string as well as anything the original automaton accepted.

In the second case, if the language does not already contain the empty string, we're done and can use the automaton for the language directly with no modification. If it does contain the empty string already, we can add a new initial state and have it transition like the original initial state. If we leave all other transitions alone and don't make this new initial state accepting, we will not accept the empty string but will continue to accept everything else.

This is the best that can be done, in general. However, specific languages might have smaller automata than these constructed after adding or removing the empty string. For instance, the language consisting of only the empty string has a DFA with two states, but a minimal DFA for that language with the empty string removed has one state. Similarly, the language of all non-empty strings has a DFA with two states, but adding the empty string to that language means there's a one-state DFA for that language. So this construction does not always give the smallest DFA possible, but it is guaranteed to work for all cases, including those where there is no smaller DFA for the language (e.g., adding the empty string to the empty language forces the addition of a new state).